# How can one click on ListView Item, to dial/call, view, ''non specified number, location or website?''

Tags: android, listview

At first I created the following fields in the class below:

```
public class AutoMobil {

// Note that this class applies to both the car hire companies and car accessory dealers and car-maintenance shops, Information Should be adjusted to suit the all the companies, dealers and shops as mentioned above.


    private int autoMobiliconId;
    private String autoMobilPhoneNumber;
    private String autoMobilLocation;
    private String autoMobilWebsite;

    public AutoMobil(String autoMobilLocation, int autoMobiliconId, String autoMobilPhoneNumber, String autoMobilWebsite) {
    super();        
    this.autoMobilLocation = autoMobilLocation;
    this.autoMobiliconId = autoMobiliconId;
    this.autoMobilPhoneNumber = autoMobilPhoneNumber;
    this.autoMobilWebsite = autoMobilWebsite;

}


    public String getAutoMobilLocation() {
        return autoMobilLocation;

    }

    public int getAutoMobiliconId() {
        return autoMobiliconId;

    }

    public String getAutoMobilPhoneNumber() {
        return autoMobilPhoneNumber;

    }


    public String getAutoMobilWebsite() {
        return autoMobilWebsite;

    }

}
```

And then  I populated my list as follows:

```
 private void populateAutoMobilList() {

    myAutoMobil.add(new AutoMobil("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=38.87676,-77.03653(Label Point)",R.drawable.g,"tel:0775269482", "http://www.toyota.com" ));`
    myAutoMobil.add(new AutoMobil("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=33.87676,-79.12366(Label Point)", R.drawable.gridwebsite,"tel:0786059016", "http://www.mandelamotors.com"));
    myAutoMobil.add(new AutoMobil( "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=38.87676,-77.03653(Label Point)", R.drawable.gridwebsite, "tel:0705721453", "http://www.hankooktires.com"));

    }
```

After populating the listView with an arrayAdapter like below.

```
 private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<AutoMobil> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRestaurantsDiscounts);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AutoMobil> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(FifthActivity.this,R.layout.travel_view, myAutoMobil);

}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View travelView = convertView;
        if (travelView == null) {
            travelView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.travel_view, parent, false);
        }

        AutoMobil currentAutoMobil = myAutoMobil.get(position);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)travelView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTravel);
        imageView.setImageResource(currentAutoMobil.getAutoMobiliconId());

        return travelView;
    }
```

Question: How should I dial a ''non specified number'' in my populated list, or visit a ''non specified website'' or view a ''non specified location'' on maps, if my codes look like above?

Comment: what is "non specifed website", "non specifed location"? Do you want visit unknow website, unknow location?

Comment: @barwnikk, Non specified number, website, or location is one that is defined in my list adapter but not in my intents. Therefore I would like to be able to click on the listView item and use one code to get the respective item number or visit the website from my list.

Comment: Look now. Do you mean about it?

Comment: Now, you must handle AdapterView.OnItemClickListener in ListView.

Answer (score 0):

To visit a page:

```
public void visitPage(String url){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

To dial a number:

```
public void dialNumber(String number){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" +number));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Permission in Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

to open google maps, you should call visitPage, this will open a dialog with "Choose an application: Google Maps, chrome, browser, etc.".

Comment: I had all that code sorted out for sure. However, for some reasons when I try to dial/call, my code does not seem to get the phone numbers or my websites in my list. May you please guide me in detail how I can use the dial codes if I am using a switch/if clause for the context menu. Thanks once again for your time.